# JavaScript getting 'unsafe-eval' with setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, unsafe-eval

I get this error with the first code snippet below

> Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is
> not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security
> Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'".

```
    class SomeClass {
     constructor(){
           
        this.startTime = 0;
        this.gameTimer = setInterval(this.myTimer(), 1000);

    }

    myTimer() {
        this.startTime++;
        document.getElementById('time-count').innerHTML = this.startTime;

    }
}
```

But with a lambda function everything works fine:

```
    class SomeClass {
      constructor(){

         this.startTime = 0;
         this.gameTimer = setInterval(() => {
             this.startTime++;
             document.getElementById('time-count').innerHTML = this.startTime;
         }, 1000);
        
    }
}
```

I would like to know is there a way to declare a method or a function that I can set as an argument in the setInterval function (what I'm calling the constructor) without getting the 'unsafe-eval' - error ?

Ps. It would be a great plus to also know why I'm getting the error in the first snippet.

Comment: In the first code example, you are passing `undefined` as a callback to `setInterval` (`this.myTimer()` returns `undefined`)

Comment: So should I pass the myTimer function to the constructor as an argument and define it outside of the SomeClass class?

Comment: You should be able to pass the method directly, but you will need to bind the `this` context to it: `setInterval(this.myTimer.bind(this), 1000);`